# SOQL - Profiles with 2FA Enabled for Login

Tags: soql, profile, two-factor-authentication

Looking for a simple query to return profiles where the UI checkbox 'Two-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins' is checked.

Workbench is blocked at work, so wasn't sure how else I could take a look at the properties a Profile object has.

Something like:

SELECT 2FAForUILogins from Profile WHERE 2FAForUILogins = 'TRUE'

Can someone offer a way to find the above in a general sense?

Comment: You dont have to use workbench, go to your developer console and use the Query Editor!!!

Comment: I was actually trying to look for the specific property name. I ended up just logging into workbench on my phone on another network and saw the field is PermissionsForceTwoFactor so it ended up being `SELECT Name,PermissionsForceTwoFactor FROM Profile where PermissionsForceTwoFactor = true` however trailhead's security specialist badge says more than one profile has this enabled which isnt true in my case so must be another permission?

Comment: got it, ya everything is tagged with permissions as fieldname mostly. I thought you were just referring to the name as such.. good luck

Comment: Cheers @Raj appreciate the heads up. For anyone in the future, these are the permission names related to 2FA from the UI - `PermissionsApiEnabled,PermissionsForceTwoFactor,PermissionsDelegatedTwoFactor,PermissionsManageTwoFactor,PermissionsTwoFactorApi`

Comment: @trebleCode, workbench is a such useful tool that I can't see myself without it. You have the ability to install workbench for your own organization. Please follow the steps in its git repo here -> https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo but Heroku is blocked where I work. Ended up googling and using workbench from a phone not on the network to look through properties